# IE: Turn Off Friendly HTTP Error Messages via server?

Tags: internet-explorer, http-headers

I know how to display "friendly" http 500 messages by configuring the IE web browser:

Here is how to do it: https://www.webwiz.net/kb/asp-tutorials/friendly-HTTP-error-messages.htm

Is there something that the web server can do, to make the real page to be displayed?

I would like to avoid this configuring at the client.

Background: In my case there is a really good error message which would help the user to understand the problem. But the user does not see it, since IE hides the nice error page.

I use Apache and Django. But I guess this should not matter in this context.

Comment: About what web server are you talking about?

Comment: @tukan 
I use Apache and Django. But I guess this should not matter in this context.

Comment: Well actually it does, I know solution for IIS 7.x which is not very useful for you :).

Comment: @tukan the response of IIS 7.x gets transferred over an tcp/ip stream as bytes. The client receives these bytes. I don't understand why IIS can create bytes which can't be created by Apache. Sorry, I can't follow you. Please elaborate your comment.

Comment: That is true, but there are different configuration options and I simply don't know how to do that on Apache (luckly I did not had to configure it for any MS application).  I thought of doing along these lines - https://community.appian.com/support/w/kb/348/kb-1126-how-to-display-detailed-error-messages-in-iis.  If that would help in your case that I'm not sure (you would need to test it) - but since it is IE it might help.

Comment: @tukan I think it would be very easy to get the valuable details. You just need a tool which can dump the response including http-headers. AFAIK curl can do this. Step1: use default Config if IIS and run curl and dump the result. Config IIS to show real error message. Run curl and dump again. Compare both files with diff. And voila: The difference is visible. With this valuable detail I can configure most other web servers accordingly. I don't have IIS around. Could you please show me the diff? Maybe as answer, not as comment. The bounty will be yours!

Comment: I would love to help, but I'm facing death in my family.  I hope to get back after I'm able to.

Comment: I hate to state the obvious,  but correct the 500 error. Instead of trying to mask its effects.

Comment: @Strom the 500 was corrected even before I wrote the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to Microsoft](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2010/08/18/friendly-http-error-pages/), IE 5+ will show a friendly error if the error response body is "too short", i.e.

- The HTTP status code is 400, 403, 404, 405, 406, 408, 409, 410,
  500, 501, or 505
- The HTTP response body length is shorter
  than a threshold value - default is 256 bytes for the response codes 403, 405, and 410; 512 bytes for response codes 400, 404, 406, 408, 409, 500, 501, and 505.

The accepted method of forcing IE to show your "friendlier" error is to ensure the response body length exceeds the threshold, typically by padding the response to > 512 bytes.

If you are generating the "really good error message" in your app, you should be able to pad it at that time.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer!